# Need to allow swivelling/rotating fitting for steel wire

Tags: hanging

I have a swing-hammock that's hanging from the ceiling (through an I-beam) with some steel wire. Everything is swell except the positioning of the hammock means it should be able to swivel. This can't happen with the current arrangement, the wire would twist and be compromised eventually (think a typical park swing and how you'd twist it up and then let it untwist at high speed).

Thus, I'm looking for the proper fitting to enable this rotation and can't seem to find one. Things like [this](http://www.sinowirerope.com/Stainless+steel+swivel/) aren't meant to operate under load, whatever I get needs to be able to handle a 250lb person and the force associated with sitting down in it and pulling out of it.

Something with bearings would be excellent I imagine, as obviously supporting weight while allowing rotation is a lot of force to handle gracefully.

Any tips would be awesome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your local mountaineering/rock climbing/etc. store (Mountain Equipment Co-Op is the one I am familiar with) will care a [Swivel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000T2BT22) device that allows for rotation while still supporting the loads seen with a swing.

[Swivel Image http://images.mec.ca/fluid/customers/c822/4001-684/4001-684_PDP_Image/main_variation_NOC02_view_view1_350x250.jpg?20110209163550](http://images.mec.ca/fluid/customers/c822/4001-684/4001-684_PDP_Image/main_variation_NOC02_view_view1_350x250.jpg?20110209163550)

The model pictured is good for a working load of 5kN which is about 1124lbs and a breaking strength of 23kN. They are expensive, however.

Comment: The original link was just back to this question, so I changed it to an Amazon product. SO gets a commission for Amazon referrals, so it helps keep the lights on.

Comment: Didn't even think of MEC, of course this would apply to climbing. That is a tad expensive, so I'd love any cheaper suggestions, but I'll keep it in consideration. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try to find some used ones.  Often, if they are dropped, climbers will no longer use it due to the possibility of failure, but will likely be fine for your use unless you happen to be hanging your hammock from a mountain

Comment: Good idea, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a [swivel bracket](http://www.bestpricetoys.com/residential-tire-swivel/) like this.

[image]